# Can anyone explain how this.id works here?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time explaining in my report exactly what this.id does here and how it works... Pls help. This is what my code looks like:

```
if (bricksTurned == 0){
        this.src = "pics/" + this.id + ".png";
        this.className = "brickFront";
        brickOne = this;
        turnedOne = this.id;
        bricksTurned = 1;
        removeListener(brickOne,"click",turn);
        return;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: "How it works" in what way? This code looks like it's meant to be in an event handler, where `this` is the element the event was hooked on. What specifically about `this.id` is hard to explain in your report? (As opposed to `this` as a general thing, as you're using it in several places.) *(not my downvote)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- this.id attaches the value that has been assigned inside the `id`
- Usually it will be this.name etc.
- But in your case I think the name of the image is stored in the `id`
  so `this.id` will have the image name.
- So this line of code : this.src = "pics/" + this.id + ".png";
- Will change to : this.src = "pics/image.png";

Hope I cleared your doubt